# Pass wordpress logged in user to field inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

I'm running a wordpress site (http://abraxas.pw) which has an embedded IRC chat in it. The IRC server runs on an aws web instance (not where the website lives) so it is loaded in an iframe. I would like to pass the WP username in to the username input field inside of the iframe but I'm uncertain if this is possible or where to being (not a coder, setting up the IRC server was hard enough, lol).

Does anyone know if this is possible and what code should go where/on what pages?

Comment: Pass GET variable to iframe `<iframe src="url?username="`

Comment: Could someone explain why the downvote? I feel that this is a legitimate question?

Comment: And use the IRC api to set the config https://kiwiirc.com/docs/scripting/api

Comment: This is a legitimate question.  +1.